# SharePoint 2013 file upload with Jquery question

Tags: 2013

I am currently developing a page which users will be able to upload from their local machines files to a SharePoint 2013 server.

Currently I have managed to experiment with the ajax calls and use the rest api for creating simple .txt files and additional folders.

The problem I am facing is a response I am getting when trying to upload a .doc file or any other file that is using an arrayBuffer as the data.

Here is my code (which again is working is the data passed is a simple string:

```
url = "http://temp-sharepoint/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')/files/add(overwrite=true,url='"+fileName+"')";

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: arrayBuffer,
                    processData: false,
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                         "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
                    },
                   success: doSuccess,
                    error: onError
                });
```

Here is how arrayBuffer is being populated:

```
function getFileBuffer(fileInput) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

The code above will result in a response of

> [object Error]{description: "The paramet...", message: "The paramet...", name: "Error", number: -2147024809, stack: "Error: The ..."}

which is `The Parameter is incorrect`.

Again if data is "Test" the file is being created with no problems.

I am quite new to SharePoint and I would appreciate if someone can point me to a possible solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure `arrayBuffer` is filled properly. Can you post code on how it is being populated.

Comment: I updated my original question to include the arraybuffer function